# Relativistic Hamiltonian with Full Mass Matrix

Tags: differential-geometry, general-relativity, hamilton-equations, special-relativity

In some application of Hamiltonian Monte Carlo one can provide a full mass matrix (metric tensor) for the kinetic energy in Hamiltonian equations:
$$ K(p) = \frac{1}{2}p^TM^{-1}p$$
which reduces to the correct definition from physical prespective when $M=mI$. For special relativity, however, the kinetic energy energy is
$$ K(p) = m c^2 \left(\frac{p^T p}{m^2 c^2} + 1\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
However, I do not see any direct way that one can have such expression for a matrix $M$.

This is of interest when we think about the Hamiltonian on a manifold. In this case the classical mass matrix is nothing more than the Riemannian metric tensor and $M^{-1}$ is the covector metric tensor (in the chosen basis). Hence, the main question is how would one write the special relativity kinetic energy on a manifold?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy#Relativistic_kinetic_energy_of_rigid_bodies

Comment: I don't have a clear answer, but you might be interested in the following two papers:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.05289
https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.04388